# Concatenate string to form scope property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm finding myself repeating a lot of code in my Angular controller because I need to update different properties on my scope based on which element fired the click handler. Below is an example:

```
vm.toggleEdit = function(activity) {
  if (activity === 'gain') {
    vm.editGain = !vm.editGain;
    vm.newGainLimit = '';
  } else if (activity === 'loss') {
    vm.editLoss = !vm.editLoss;
    vm.newWithdrawalLimit = '';
  } else {
    vm.editNeutral = !vm.editNeutral;
    vm.newNeutralLimit = '';
  }
};
```

What I'd like to do is utilize the `activity` parameter more efficiently. For example:

```
vm.edit + activity = !vm.edit + activity;
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
vm["edit" + activity] = whatever;
```

Note that your `activity` values start with lower-case letters, so you'll have to deal with that.

Seems like maybe your data structure should look like:

```
var vm = {
  gain: {
    edit: true,
    newLimit: ''
  },
  loss: {
    edit: false,
    newLimit: ''
  },
  // etc
};
```

That way your `activity` value would select a sub-object, and all those would be similar.